# Joining feature matrix and target vector in R with complicated logic

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a feature vector like this:

```
   rest_id qtr cooking cleaning eating jumping
1      123   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
2      123   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
3      123   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
4      123   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
5      435   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
6      435   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
7      435   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
8      435   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
9      437   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
10     437   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
11     437   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE    TRUE
12     437   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
13     439   2   FALSE     TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
```

And a target vector like this:

```
   rest_id qtr target
1      123   1   TRUE
2      123   2  FALSE
3      123   3  FALSE
4      123   4   TRUE
5      123   5   TRUE
6      435   1   TRUE
7      435   2   TRUE
8      435   3   TRUE
9      435   4  FALSE
10     435   5  FALSE
11     437   1   TRUE
12     437   2   TRUE
13     437   3   TRUE
14     437   4  FALSE
15     439   3  FALSE
```

I want to join these two together such that

- Feature Q1 -> Target Q1Q2
- Feature Q2 -> Target Q2Q3
- Feature Q3 -> Target Q3Q4
- Feature Q4 -> Target Q4Q5

For example if the feature observation is in quarter 1, we check quarter 1 and 2 of the target vector for that `rest_id` and `quarter` : if they are both TRUE the target becomes TRUE, if they are both FALSE the target becomes FALSE, and if they are TRUE and FALSE they the target becomes TRUE.

The intended output would look like this:

```
rest_id  qtr cooking cleaning eating jumping target
123      1   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
123      2   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
123      3   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
123      4   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
435      1   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
435      2   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
435      3   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
435      4   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
437      1   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
437      2   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
437      3   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
437      4   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
```

I cant do this with just a regular join in R because of the complicated logic I mentioned.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: there are some cases where the target doesn't exist for a quarter. I added an example where the `rest_id` is 437. If for example the feature vector instance is Q4, we check for Q4 and Q5. Q5 doesn't exist so we just use Q4. If both do not exist then it should be NA.

Comment: they are data frames!

Comment: So if the feature data is Q2, I would check for the same establishment Q2 and Q3. If for example Q2 target is TRUE and Q3 target is FALSE, then the final target should be TRUE.

Comment: because for rest_id =  `123` and for `quarter` = 2, we check the target for Q2 and Q3 and they are both FALSE so the final target should be FALSE

Comment: We look at the target vector, for that example these are the rows of interest and they are bobth false
```
123      2   FALSE
123      3   FALSE
```

Comment: I"m kinda confused. When rest_id is 123 and quarter is in 1 in the feature matrix, you check for q1 and q2 of the target vector. In this case, the target vector is TRUE for Q1 and FALSE for Q2, meaning the final target should be TRUE. which is shown in the end result output

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  complete(qtr, rest_id) %>%
  group_by(rest_id) %>%
  mutate(target = as.logical(pmax(target, lead(target), na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  right_join(dat2, by = c("rest_id", "qtr")) %>%
  relocate(target, .after = last_col()) %>%
  arrange(rest_id)

# A tibble: 13 x 7
# Groups:   rest_id [4]
     qtr rest_id cooking cleaning eating jumping target
   <int>   <int> <lgl>   <lgl>    <lgl>  <lgl>   <lgl> 
 1     1     123 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  
 2     2     123 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE 
 3     3     123 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  
 4     4     123 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  
 5     1     435 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  
 6     2     435 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  
 7     3     435 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  
 8     4     435 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE 
 9     1     437 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  
10     2     437 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  
11     3     437 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  TRUE    TRUE  
12     4     437 FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE 
13     2     439 FALSE   TRUE     TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
```

Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(rest_id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 435L, 
435L, 435L, 435L, 435L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 439L), qtr = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L), target = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

dat2 <- structure(list(rest_id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 435L, 435L, 
435L, 435L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 439L), qtr = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,2L), cooking = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), cleaning = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), eating = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), jumping = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was my intended output

Comment: If there is an instance where there doesn't exist a quarter 5 in the target, the value for the final target becomes NA even if quarter 5 is FALSE. Is there a workaround for this? I added an edit to my post for clarification

Comment: I just added an edit to the dataframes for a specific example  (id = 439) where quarters are missing. This example shows as NA when it shouldn't be labelled as NA. The NA (quarter 2) entry should be FALSE since  quarter 3 is FALSE

Comment: Thank you for the solusions. I just updated again for another edge case, i'm still getting NA's for certain values if some of the quarters are NA

Comment: With the edits I think you should post a new question with the data and desired output including explaining what to do in the edge cases you mention.

Comment: Like for example. If I have a quarter 1 observation in the feature set, I need to look at quarter 1 and quarter 2 in the target vector. Sometimes either quarter 1 or quarter 2 or both can be missing. If only one is missing you just go with the one that is not missing. If both are missing than it is a valid NA. The same logic applies to the other cases. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I added a new question with clarification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412994/complicated-feature-matrix-and-target-vector-join-in-r

Comment: The code I provided above returns the expected output for your new question (just note that it sorts by rest_id so case 234 is no longer on the bottom).  Not sure how to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'target' dataset rows are ordered in 'rest_id' and 'qtr', we can do a `rollmax` on the 'target' after grouping by 'rest_id' specifying the 'k' as 2, then we can use `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
dat %>% 
     group_by(rest_id) %>%
     mutate(target = as.logical(zoo::rollmax(target, k = 2, 
            fill = NA))) %>% 
     left_join(dat2, .)%>%
     mutate(target = replace_na(target, FALSE))
#  rest_id qtr cooking cleaning eating jumping target
#1      123   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#2      123   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE
#3      123   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#4      123   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#5      435   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#6      435   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#7      435   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#8      435   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE
#9      437   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#10     437   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#11     437   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
#12     437   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE
```

#### data

```html
dat <- structure(list(rest_id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 435L, 
435L, 435L, 435L, 435L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L), qtr = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), target = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

dat2 <- structure(list(rest_id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 435L, 435L, 
435L, 435L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 437L), qtr = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), cooking = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), cleaning = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), eating = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), jumping = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: This is perfect. However I just realized that some quarters in my target vector don't exist..I added an edit to my post

Comment: @Eisen If there are quarters that doesn't exist, then use `complete` i.e. `dat %>% complete(rest_id, qtr = 1:5, fill = list(target = FALSE)) %>%`. In that case, do you need `FALSE` for target?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to impute a FALSE for missing quarters here because they didn't happen

Comment: @Eisen then you could add  `%>% mutate(target = replace_na(target, FALSE))` with the current solution to get expected

Comment: why would we replace it with FALSE when theres a possibility it could be TRUE?

Comment: is there a way to dynamically do this? for example if we have quarter 2 observation in the feature matrix we check for quarter 2 and quarter 3 target in the target vector. if one of the quarters is missing we choose the result for the remaining column, if both are missing then it is a valid NA. the logical would apply similarity for the other quarters (1, 3,4)

Comment: @Eisen that is the reason I said `complete` would be an option.  where we have `NA` by default for target and then when we do the group by with `roll_max`, it selects the top one after removing the NA