# complicated feature matrix and target vector join in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I asked a similar question here: [Joining feature matrix and target vector in R with complicated logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402737/joining-feature-matrix-and-target-vector-in-r-with-complicated-logic/63403008?noredirect=1#comment112115499_63403008)

But I've created a new question due to the confusion and unclear prompt I had.

I have a feature vector like this:

```
   rest_id qtr cooking cleaning eating jumping
1      123   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
2      123   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
3      123   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
4      123   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
5      435   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
6      435   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
7      435   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
8      435   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
9      437   1   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
10     437   2   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
11     437   3   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE    TRUE
12     437   4   FALSE     TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
13     439   2   FALSE     TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
14     508   1   FALSE     TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
15     508   2   FALSE     TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
16     234   2   FALSE     TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
```

And a target vector like this:

```
   rest_id qtr target
1      123   1   TRUE
2      123   2  FALSE
3      123   3  FALSE
4      123   4   TRUE
5      123   5   TRUE
6      435   1   TRUE
7      435   2   TRUE
8      435   3   TRUE
9      435   4  FALSE
10     435   5  FALSE
11     437   1   TRUE
12     437   2   TRUE
13     437   3   TRUE
14     437   4  FALSE
15     439   3  FALSE
16     508   3  FALSE
17     508   5  FALSE
18     234   3  TRUE
```

I want to join these two together such that

- Feature Q1 -> Target Q1Q2
- Feature Q2 -> Target Q2Q3
- Feature Q3 -> Target Q3Q4
- Feature Q4 -> Target Q4Q5

For example if the feature observation is in quarter 1, we check quarter 1 and 2 of the target vector for that `rest_id` and `quarter` : if they are both TRUE the target becomes TRUE, if they are both FALSE the target becomes FALSE, and if they are TRUE and FALSE they the target becomes TRUE. The same logic applies for Q2,Q3,Q4.

However there are some missing quarters in the target vector. If we are looking at quarter 1 in our feature vector, we check the target for the same `rest_id` for Q1 and Q3. There are three cases that can happen:

- Q1 is missing and Q2 is not missing ---> take the target value for Q2
- Q2 is not missing and Q1 is missing ---> take target value for Q1
- Q1 and Q2 are both missing ---> should be N/A

The intended output would look like this:

```
rest_id  qtr cooking cleaning eating jumping target
123      1   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
123      2   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
123      3   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
123      4   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
435      1   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
435      2   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
435      3   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
435      4   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
437      1   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
437      2   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
437      3   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
437      4   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
439      2   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
508      1   FALSE   TRUE     TRUE   FALSE   N/A
508      2   FALSE   TRUE     TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
234      2   FALSE   TRUE     TRUE   FALSE   TRUE
```

I cant do this with just a regular join in R because of the complicated logic I mentioned.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` way (since the question is tagged with it):

```
library(tidyverse)

expand_grid(rest_id = unique(feature_vector$rest_id), qtr = 1:5) %>%
  arrange(rest_id, qtr) %>%
  left_join(target_vector) %>%
  group_by(rest_id) %>%
  mutate(lead_target = lead(target)) %>%
  mutate(aimed_target = case_when(!is.na(target) & is.na(lead_target) ~ target,
                                  is.na(target) & !is.na(lead_target) ~ lead_target,
                                  TRUE ~ target|lead_target)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(feature_vector) %>%
  select(rest_id, qtr, cooking, cleaning, eating, jumping, aimed_target) %>%
  rename(target = aimed_target)
```

1. First I create a combination of all `rest_id`s in the feature vector, and `qtr` from 1 to 5 using `expand_grid()`. Then I use `arrange()` to make the grid sorted (this is redundant if `rest_id` is already sorted in the first place).
2. Then I use `left_join()` to join the `target_vector` to the aforementioned grid. These first two steps are done so that every missing `rest_id` and `qtr` combination is granted a `NA` value in the column `target`.
3. I create column `lead_target`, the reason is because you'll always want the current quarter and the next quarter's `target` value. Now, I can make one row have both via `lead()`. Before that I use `group_by()` so the `lead()` function is done on similar `rest_id`s only.
4. `aimed_target` is pretty much created using logic that you specify. I use `case_when()` as a replacement to multiple `ifelse()` functions. The operator `|` is "or", in case you wonder.
5. The rest of the code is pretty straightforward. I need to drop some columns and rename in the end.

---